# integrating paypal check without leaving your site

Tags: paypal

I want to integrate paypal in my website. But my requirement is, I dont want my customers to go into paypal site for payment. (I know it is not a secure way, but it is my requirements) Is there a way such that I can do credit card checks in backend using paypal APIs ?  If so, which method to be used? I want it for "singapore" country and SGD as currency.

Waiting for your suggestions!!!

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is called Direct Payment. Here is more info about it:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayment

Comment: Curious to know what the new answer to this is, as "Direct Payment" has been removed from that page.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to avoid your users having to navigate to PayPal or are you trying to 'hide' the use of PayPal?

The prior should be easy enough to resolve. PayPay provide several tools (and instructions) on how to build a "Pay Now" button, which you can manipulate server side to include a dynamic amount and order ID etc. This would forward the user to a PayPal page to login and confirm payment, then return them to your site (any page you specify) on completion. You can also link this to an IPN. The PayPal payment page can be skinned / branded to an extent.

Comment: I want them not to goto paypal, but they enter their information in my site and i check payments using paypal API. something like "do direct payment" but I think it is allowed only in United States. Any Idea?

Comment: Personally, as a consumer, I wouldn't enter my paypal details on a third-party's website. Linking to the PayPal invoice screen (and having it return to your site afterwards), together with some branding is the best bet. You can do this fairly seamlessly at the end of your checkout process. Otherwise your site is on the verge of phishing.

Comment: I enter credit card information on vendor websites. I don't have to navigate to visa or mastercard's website to enter that and then come back to the vendor site. I can't say that seems like phishing to me, so why would it be with paypal?

Comment: If you have someone's email address and PayPal password, that's all PayPal use to grant access to your account. Would you give a site your on line banking credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this [Paypal product](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/compare_wp_products#secondpage)

Comment: How about an explanation of what the link is in your answer?

Comment: The link compared two products, one allows folks to pay within the website without going to paypal, while the other requires guests to first visit paypal before making payment.

Comment: I have a question regarding this - there are three different options: standard, advanced and pro. The latter two offer paying without leaving the site. However, when I take a look at API documentation, I don't see anywhere that this advanced account is mentioned, only the pro one. Has this changed in the meantime, or... ???